# Async/Await with node-pg on digitalocean not returning anything

Tags: node.js, postgresql, async-await, node-pg-pool

Hi I am trying to fetch data from server/index.js api endpoint `data.getData()` which is provided from api/data.js which in turn gets it's configuration and connection object from db/index.js. The problem is that the async/await is not returning anything and in the dev console  network says pending. I don't receive any errors either. The code is below. Using node-pg with pool.query.

```
//server/index.js
const express = require("express");
const data = require("./api/data")

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const app = express();
app.use(express.json())

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    // res.status(200).send('Hello World!');

    await data.getData()
    .then(response => {
      res.status(200).send(console.log(response));
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).send(error);
      })
    console.log("server running")
})


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});


//api/data.js
const db = require('../db/index.js');

const getData = async () => {
    const query = {
        // text: 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM "public"."Subregions-USA";',
        text: 'SELECT Now()',
        // values: ['B007RKDGVQ'],
        // rowMode: 'array',
    };
    
    const dbResults = await db.query(query)
    .then((data) => JSON.stringify(data))
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
    console.log("database response test")

    return dbResults
}

// getData()

module.exports = {getData}
```

The setup is pretty simple but i can't understand why it is not working.
[image]

I am trying to connect to postgresql in digital ocean and all the connections and configs are correct. I have used the same setup similar but with electron.js and it works. I am able to retrieve the data easily.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `res.status(200).send(response);`

Comment: @hoangdv I have tried that it doesn't work, i tried several things, can't send the response and either console it.

Comment: try to make your code cleaner. if you use `.then/catch`, don't use `async/await`. If you use `async/await` don't use `then/catch`. I guess `console.log(error)` line be called.

Comment: So what does your code log? Where does it hang?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found the problem and it has nothing to do with the logic itself but more with the package I installed for PostgreSQL.

Instead of installing `npm i pg` I did instead `npm i node-pg` for some stupid reason.

After uninstalling and installing the correct package I am able to work with the PostgreSQL response.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid using both `async/await` and `then/catch` at the same time. Use one of them.

- **server/index.js**

```js
const express = require("express");
const data = require("./api/data")

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const app = express();
app.use(express.json())

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  // res.status(200).send('Hello World!');

  try {
    const result = await data.getData();

    res.status(200).send(result);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
  console.log("server running")
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

- **api/data.js**

```js
const db = require('../db/index.js');

const getData = async () => {
  const query = {
    // text: 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM "public"."Subregions-USA";',
    text: 'SELECT Now()',
    // values: ['B007RKDGVQ'],
    // rowMode: 'array',
  };

  const dbResults = await db.query(query);
  console.log("database response test", dbResults)

  return JSON.stringify(dbResults)
}

module.exports = {getData}
```